# Enumerate all palindromic numbers (in decimal) between 0 and n

Tags: code-golf, number

Given a non-negative integer n, enumerate all palindromic numbers (in decimal) between 0 and n (inclusive range). A palindromic number remains the same when its digits are reversed.

The first palindromic numbers (in base 10) are given [here](http://oeis.org/A002113):

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 101,
>   111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 202, 212, 222, 232, 242,
>   252, 262, 272, 282, 292, 303, 313, 323, 333, 343, 353, 363, 373, 383,
>   393, 404, 414, 424, 434, 444, 454, 464, 474, 484, 494, 505, 515, ...

This is a code golf with the prize going to fewest characters. The palindromic numbers should be output one per line to stdout. The program should read n from the commandline or stdin.

Comment: Between 1 and n (as per title) or 0 and n (as per body)? And which of the bounds does "between" include?

Comment: @wok: You still haven't answered if it's inclusive or exclusive range?  Is `n` part of the range to include?

Comment: @mellamokb Inclusive range.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Golfscript, 15 chars

```
~),{.`-1%~=},n*
```

Comment: You may save a char comparing strings instead of numbers '~),{`.-1%=},n*'.

Comment: @Howard, if you want to post that yourself I'll upvote it.

Comment: That would feel like plain copying ;-)

Answer (score 10):

### Perl 5.10, 29 (or 39) characters

```
say for grep$_==reverse,0..<>
```

Needs the `say` feature enabled. 29 chars if you consider that to be free,  otherwise 39 to add `use 5.010;`. Argument on STDIN.

### Perl, 35 characters

```
#!perl -l
print for grep $_==reverse,0..<>
```

using the old perlgolf convention that `#!perl` is not counted but any flags following it are.

### Perl, 36 characters

```
print$_,$/for grep $_==reverse,0..<>
```

If none of the others qualify.

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain what does $/ do?

Comment: @Gurzo `$/` is the input record separator, which defaults to newline. It's just a little shorter than literal `"\n"`.

Comment: Using map is shorter: `map{say if$_==reverse}0..<>`

Comment: @jho evil. Submit it :)

Comment: If you use `-E` in lieu of `-e`, you get `say` for free.

Answer (score 9):

### Befunge <strike>320</strike> <strike>313</strike> 303 characters

(including significant newlines and whitespace)

```
 &:#v_v#  #                  :-1<
v91:<         v          <
0     >0.@    >\25**\1-:#^_v
pv   p09+1g09<^_           >$+     v
:>:25*%\25*/:| ^:p18:+1g18\<
 :          > >90g 1-:90p  | >  ^
>|           $^     <      >-|  ^  #<
 @           > 0 81p^        >:.25*,^
            ^                      <
```

I wonder if I could make this smaller by rerouting the paths...

Edit: redid the top part to avoid an extra line.

Answer (score 8):

### Perl 5.10 - 27 characters

`map{say if$_==reverse}0..<>`

Reads the argument from stdin.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby 1.9, 39 characters

```
puts (?0..gets).select{|i|i==i.reverse}
```

Input (must not be terminated with a newline) via stdin. Example invocation:

```
echo -n 500 | ruby1.9 palinenum.rb
```

40 characters for a version which uses commandline args:

```
puts (?0..$*[0]).select{|i|i==i.reverse}
```

Comment: [Rohit](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2515/rohit) proposed saving 3 characters in each of these by using `p` instead of `puts`.

Comment: Using your code I got the following output, which seems to be wrong(I am using ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18) [i386-mingw32])

`irb(main):023:0> p (?0..gets).select{|i|i==i.reverse}

1

["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88", "
99"]

=> ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "22", "33", "44", "55", "66", "77", "88"
, "99"]
`
The code below works for me

`p ('0'..gets[0..-2]).select{|i|i==i.reverse}`

Could you explain your code.

Comment: @PeterTaylor @Rohit `p` and `puts` are not equivalent, in fact using `p` breaks the output, as puts [writes every element on a newline, if called with an array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-putc), whereas `p` simply calls `.to_s`.

Answer (score 6):

### [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 20 characters

```
(#~(-:|.)@":"0)>:i.n
```

Comment: I can read it!:) Nice

Comment: btw, to meet a requirement output numbers one per line you should add `,"0`.

Comment: @defhlt `,.` works as well

Answer (score 5):

### Python, <strike>57</strike> 51 chars

```
for i in range(input()):
 if`i`==`i`[::-1]:print i
```

Usage:

```
echo 500 | python palindromic.py
```

Comment: Shorter: `for i in range(input()):if\`i\`==\`i\`[::-1]:print i`

Comment: *If* using the interactive interpreter is legit, then you can avoid the `print` and just do ``if`i`==`i`[::-1]:i`` (I say this because the Scala solution depends on this).

Comment: The range should be inclusive.
And i think you can change you byte count to 50 (linebreaks are shorter on linux).

Answer (score 5):

**Perl > 5.10 : 25 characters**

```
map$_==reverse&&say,0..<>
```

Answer (score 4):

#### APL (<s>25</s> 17)

```
↑t/⍨t≡∘⌽¨t←⍕¨0,⍳⎕
```

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript <del>122</del> <del>108</del> 107 chars...

I'm sure this can be golfed more - I'm new to this!

```
n=prompt(o=[]);for(i=0;i<=n;i++)if(i+''==(i+'').split("").reverse().join(""))o.push(i);alert(o.join("\n"));
```

#### or

```
n=prompt(o=[]);i=-1;while(i++<n)if(i+''==(i+'').split("").reverse().join(""))o.push(i);alert(o.join("\n"));
```

Comment: Well, for starters the `var`s are unneeded, you can just make things global. Also `prompt()` doesn't strictly need parameters.

Comment: However, you *can* use parameters to `prompt()` to save one semicolon: `n=prompt(o=[]);`.

Comment: Also you still have a `var i=0` that can have the `var` removed in your `for`.

Comment: Something's wrong with your code.  It prints out every number between 0 and n-1, not just the palindromes, in both FF and Chrome...  Aha found it.  You need parentheses: `(i+'').split...` otherwise you are reversing `''` only :)  BTW you can easily test your code with jsfiddle, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/rU5Vh/

Comment: Also if I read the question right, it's inclusive of 0 and n.  So that should really be `i<=n` rather than `i<n` in the `for`.

Comment: You can save a few more chars by moving `i=0` declaration outside and switching `for` to a `while` loop: `while(i++<n)`.

Comment: hmm mellamokb thanks for all the tips. :) I had the brackets before .split before but must have stupidly removed them to try and save chars without noticing. That `while(i++<n)` won't that a) remove 0 from the numbers and b) not get to i==n.

Comment: I set `i=-1` and it works with the `while` loop. Why does `while(i++<n)` also match true when `i+1=n`?

Comment: The trick is that `i++<n` compares `i<n` before adding 1 to `i`.  Thus, it runs all the way to `i=n`.  If you wanted to stop at `i=n-1`, you would use `++i<n` instead.

Comment: `alert(o.join(" "))` needs to be `alert(o.join("\n"))` according to the specs. Add 1 to your character count when you fix this.

Comment: @mellamokb In JS, a for loop should never require more characters than its equivalent while loop. Instead of `i=-1;while(i++<n)` you can use `for(i=-1;i++<n;)` to save a character.

Comment: I think using `console.log()` does not violate the rules, but reduces the code to 84 characters: `for(i=0,n=prompt();i<=n;i++)if(i==(i+'').split('').reverse().join(''))console.log(i)`.

Comment: You could make this even shorter by using `for(i=0;++i<=n;)` instead of `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)`.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell 66 characters

```
main=do n<-readLn;mapM_ putStrLn[s|s<-map show[0..n],s==reverse s]
```

Comment: Misspelled the language name...

Comment: Fixed (filler chars)

Answer (score 3):

### Perl - 43 chars

```
for$i(0..<>){if($i==reverse$i){print$i,$/}}
```

This is my first attempt at code golf, so I'm pretty sure a Perl pro could golf it down.

Answer (score 3):

**Mathematica 61**

```
Column@Select[0~Range~Input[],#==Reverse@#&@IntegerDigits@#&]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog)

### With the I/O format stated in the question, 8 bytes

```
≥ℕA↔A≜ẉ⊥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#ARoA5f//4oml4oSVQeKGlEHiiZzhuoniiqX//zUwMA)

### With modern PPCG I/O rules, 4 bytes

```
≥ℕ.↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#q37UtuFRU9Ojzjm1D7ct@P@oc@mjlql6j9qm/P9vagAE/6MA)

This is a function that generates all the outputs, not a full program like the previous example, and so doesn't comply with the spec as written, but I thought I'd show how the program would look like if the question had been written to modern I/O standards (which permit the use of functions, and output via generators).

## Explanation

```
≥ℕ.↔ 
 ℕ    Generate natural numbers
≥     less than or equal to the input
  .   but output only the ones
   ↔  that would produce the same output if reversed
```

For the full program version, we create a temporary variable `A` to hold the output, explicitly labelize it (this is done implicitly for the main predicate of a program), and use the well-known `ẉ⊥` technique for outputting a generator's elements to standard output.

Comment: When did modern PPCG I/O rules allow you to use a generator as submission?

Comment: @LeakyNun: I made the proposal on [30 Nov 2016](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/62131), but the consensus is that they were already legal at that point (just not documented). We have an explicit rule allowing them now; through most of 2016, they weren't explicitly allowed and they weren't explicitly banned either.

Comment: Oh, well, I see.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <del>64</del> 58 bytes

```
for($i=0;$i<=$argv[1];print$i==strrev($i)?$i.'\n':'',$i++)
```

Changed `$_GET['n']` to `$argv[1]` for command line input.

Answer (score 2):

### **PHP, <strike>59</strike> <strike>55</strike> 53 chars**

```
for($i=0;$i++<$argv[1];)if($i==strrev($i))echo"$i\n";
```

Usage

```
php palindromic.php 500
```

Edit : thanks Thomas

Comment: you can remove the {s around the for loop and remove the space in `echo "$i\n"` to get `echo"$i\n"`. That'll save you a few chars. Also, if you want to be cheeky you can change `\n` for ` ` and save a char.

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala 59

```
(0 to readInt)filter(x=>""+x==(""+x).reverse)mkString("\n")
```

Comment: I don't know any Scala, but does that really print on stdout? I would've guessed it's an expression returning a string.

Comment: In the interactive scala REPL, yes. You may test it here http://www.simplyscala.com/ but have to replace `readInt` with a concrete number, online.

Answer (score 2):

### C, 98 characters

```
n,i,j,t;main(){for(scanf("%d",&n);i<=n;i-j?1:printf("%d ",i),i++)for(t=i,j=0;t;t/=10)j=j*10+t%10;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## k (23 chars)

```
{i@&{&/i=|i:$x}'i:!1+x}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, 97 (grid size 37x4=148)

```
#v&#:< ,*25-$#1._.@
:>:::01-\0v >-!#^_$1-
*\25*/:!#v_::1>\#* #*25*#\/#$:_$\25*%
   `-10:\<+_v#
```

Have a better Befunge answer to this question. This is Befunge-93 specifically; I could probably make it even more compact with Befunge-98. I'll include that in a future edit.

Since you can't operate on strings in Befunge, the best I could do was compute the digit-reverse of each number (which I'm surprised I was able to manage without `p` and `g`) and compare it to the original number. The digit-reverse takes up most of the code (basically the entire third and fourth lines).

Note that the program, as it stands now, prints the numbers backwards from the input down to 0. If this is a big deal, let me know. (The challenge only says to enumerate them, not specifically in increasing order.)

Comment: +1. Lines can be closed by `\n` alone, so it's 94 bytes long. I don't think your "grid size" has any particular relevance.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ƒNÂQ–
```

Explanation:

```
ƒ      # For N in range(0, input() + 1)
 N     #   Push N
  Â    #   Bifurcate (pushes N and N[::-1])
   Q   #   Check for equality
    –  #   If true, pop and print N
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xpJOw4JR4oCT&input=MTAwMA).

Comment: `LʒÂQ` is 4, non-competing still though..

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn That doesn't work, as it uses the range \$1-n\$, not \$0-n\$. Also, it outputs a list, not numbers on separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ŻŒḂƇY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7qOTHu5oOtYe@f9w@///hgYGAA)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't join the output list on newlines. I hope it doesn't cost any extra bytes to fix this.

Comment: @Lyxal Unsurprisingly, it does. Stupid older challenges and their crappy I/O formats

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

```perl
map$_-reverse||say,0..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlXrcotSy1qDi1pqY4sVLHQE/Pxu7/f0MDg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Answer (score 1):

## Python

```
n=raw_input('')
for a in range(0,int(n)+1):
    r=str(a)
    if str(a)==r[::-1]:
        print r
```

Comment: Hmm...232 characters is not really very competitive. Perhaps you could reduce the variable names to one character and delete the spaces between the variables and operators?

Comment: Good job. Some good tips for golfing Python can be found in this question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python

Comment: You can get rid of n --just replace int(n) by int(raw_input())-- and you can change str(a) to r in the if statement

Comment: @Omar that can be golfed even more. `int(raw_input())` can be just `input()`, the `0,` in the range is unnecessary, and you can use a map to map `str` over the range instead of using `r`. Also, the `print` statement can be on the same line as the `if` statement, and indentation can be a single space. This saves a whole 38 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoAwCADA3VcwtlGT1pHElxgHBqsMUoI4@Hq808@vLktE6wYELHCTpsdtMpLzSCz6espjzRkH4Aa0rrQhznVHNRYHiqillB8 "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 83

```
System.in.eachLine{(0..it.toInteger()).each{if("$it"=="$it".reverse())println(it)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Q (33)

```
{if[x="I"$(|:) -3!x;:x]} each til
```

Probably a neater way to do this but anyway, sample usage (you enter n+1 to get to n):

```
q){if[x="I"$(|:) -3!x;:x]} each til  10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Suggestion by tmartin, gets it down to 29:

```
({$[x="I"$(|:) -3!x;x;]}')(!)
```

Same usage.

Answer (score 1):

## Q (34 chars)

Pass n rather than n+1 as an argument for this Q solution.

```
{i(&)({all i=(|)i:($)x}')i:(!)1+x}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Q,32

```
{a(&)a~'((|:)')a:((-3!)')(!)1+x}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 106 characters

```
import sys as a
print(type(a.argv[1]))
for x in range(int(a.argv[1])+1):
 x=str(x)
 if x==x[::-1]:print(x)
```

usage:

```
python a.py 500
```

Comment: [82 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fco7CoAwDADQvafI2CqCFVwCnkQcOtjaoR/SIvH0UccHrz79KnkR8VQStKdBTLVQH5QvBAwxA7kcTh1z147CvdvDjNagAt5aJ81GQfQfNt4RJ3tgpf@yEZF1nl8)

Answer (score 1):

## C# (<strike>217</strike> <strike>214</strike> 191 chars)

Golfed version:

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(){int n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());do{var t=(n+"").ToArray();Array.Reverse(t);Console.Write(n+""==new string(t)?n+"\n":"");}while(n-->0);Console.ReadLine();}}
```

Readable:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        do
        {
            var t = (n + "").ToArray();
            Array.Reverse(t);
            Console.Write(n + "" == new string(t) ? n + "\n" : "");
        } while (n-->0);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This prints out palindromes in descending order making use of the n-->0 operator. (as n goes to 0).

*Edited version replaces do...while with while, saving 3 chars, but now you must input with n+1.

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(){int n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());while(n-->0){var t=(n+"").ToArray();Array.Reverse(t);Console.Write(n+""==new string(t)?n+"\n":"");}Console.ReadLine();}}
```

*edited: found a better way to reverse string without converting to array:

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(){int n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());while(n-->0)Console.Write(n+""==string.Join("",(""+n).Reverse())?n+"\n":"");Console.ReadLine();}}
```

Readable:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (n-->0)
            Console.Write(n + "" == string.Join("", ("" + n).Reverse()) ? n + "\n" : ""); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 53

Can 53 be any lower? Four different options:

```
for($i=$argv[1];$i-->0;)echo$i==strrev($i)?"$i\n":"";
for($i=$argv[1];$i-->0;)if($i==strrev($i))echo"$i\n";
while(($i=$argv[1]--)>0)echo$i==strrev($i)?"$i\n":"";
while(($i=$argv[1]--)>0)if($i==strrev($i))echo"$i\n";
```

If you want to get funky...

**PHP 47**

```
while(($i=$argv[1]--)>0)if($i==strrev($i))`$i`;
```

You have to ignore the error text. The palindrome numbers are still output to the command line, however.

Answer (score 1):

## Burlesque, 13

```
rz{J<-==}f[p^
```

Burlesque has some useful commands for golfing, in this case <- reverses anything you put before it.

```
          rz             creates a range from 0 to input
            {            start of filtering (discards any element not returning 1) the created range
              J <- ==    duplicates element, reverses duplicate, compare
            }f[          end filtering, now we're left with a block of palindromic integer which
            p^           takes care of, and outputs the numbers as desired.
```

[Try it here](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=1000rz%7BJ%3C-%3D%3D%7Df%5Bp%5E) The linked example has 1000 as input, change it to see more or fewer palindromic numbers.

Comment: How does your script accept the input? In your example it seems to be part of the script itself.

Comment: @har-wradim Burlesque takes input the same way as Golfscript does. Meaning that input is placed on the stack before the program code.  [input][code]. In my program above input can be any positive number (the linked example has 1000 for input), which will be followed by the code rz{J<-==}f[p^  You can change the 1000 to 10 000 or  100 000 and the code will run all the palindromic number up until the input value.

Comment: GolfScript [is expected to push](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/tutorial.html) what comes from stdin on top of the stack by default. If this behavior is absent from the Burlesque specifications than your solution seems to violate one of the requirements.

Comment: @har-wradim As does Burlesque. I linked to the online shell for ease of access, but feel free to download and compile the Burlesque source code to check the different ways it can read input.

Comment: @har-wradim wait, it's because I put [Input n] in my explenation, isn't it? Solved!

Comment: Burlesque doesn't really specify how input is provided to the program, that's up to the implementation to decide. The recommendation in the 'specification' is to push STDIN as a string to the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 11

```
VhQIq`N_`NN
```

Example:

```
$ pyth -c 'VhQIq`N_`NN' <<< 200
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
101
111
121
131
141
151
161
171
181
191
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <strike>145</strike> 143

```
#include<iostream> 
int i,j,n,r;int main(){std::cin>>n;for(;i<=n;i++){j=i;while(j!=0){r=r*10;r=r+j%10;j=j/10;}if(i==r)std::cout<<i<<' ';r=0;}}
```

**Alternative [143 too]:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i,j,n,r;int main(){scanf("%d",&n);for(;i<=n;i++){j=i;while(j!=0){r=r*10;r=r+j%10;j=j/10;}if(i==r)printf("%d ", i);r=0;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python** (54)

```
print filter(lambda i:`i`==`i`[::-1],range(input()+1))
```

Comment: Added print staement

Answer (score 1):

## Gogh, 17 bytes

This answer is non-competing, as the language was created after the challenge was posted.

```
G{÷÷sR=¦?}m0%{Ƥ}m
```

Usage:

```
$ ./gogh i 'G{÷÷sR=¦?}m0%{Ƥ}m' <input>
```

---

#### Explanation

```
        “ Implicit input.                                      ”
G       “ Push an inclusive list.                              ”
{       “ Open a code block.                                   ”
 ÷÷     “ Push two copies of the TOS.                          ”
 sR=    “ Check if the integer is palindromic.                 ”
 ¦?     “ If n is palindromic, yield n. If not, yield 0.       ”
}m      “ Close the code block and map it to the TOS.          ”
0%      “ Remove non-palindromic integers (denoted by zeroes). ”
{       “ Open a code block.                                   ”
 Ƥ      “ Print.                                               ”
}m      “ Close the code block and map it to the TOS.          ”
        “ Implicit output.                                     ”
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <sup><s>34</s></sup> 33 bytes

```sh
eval \>{0..$1}';ls `ls|rev`;rm *'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/tSwxRyHGrtpAT0/FsFbdOqdYISGnuKYotSzBuihXQUv9////hgYGBgA)

- `{0..$1}` - repeat the string with this part substituted with the numbers from `0` to the input
- `eval`uate that

  - `>` - create the file with that number
  - `ls` - list all the files in the current directory
  - `|rev` - reverse that
  - `` ls `ls|rev` `` - print the intersection of the files in the current directory and the output of `ls|rev` (i.e. filter palindromes)
  - `rm *` - remove all files

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
#S=↔Θḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8b9ysO2jtinnZjzcsfj////RhjqGBkAExgaxAA)

'Enumerates' palindromic numbers (so, outputs how many there are).  To list all of them, use `fS=↔Θḣ` for the [same number of bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X9asO2jtinnZjzcsfj////RhjqGBkAExgaxAA).

```
#        # number of elements that
 S=      # are equal to themselves after
   ↔     # reversing their digits,
    Θḣ   # among 0 followed by 1..input.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `j`, <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
'Ḃ=
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=%27%E1%B8%82%3D&inputs=515&header=&footer=)

Pretty simple answer really.

### Explained

```
'Ḃ=
'     # Filter by:
 Ḇ=   #     Bifuricate the argument passed and check if the two results are equal
      # The `j` flag joins on newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ô°hånⁿ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=93f868866efc&i=515)

-1 byte from Weijun Zhou's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>84</s> <s>81</s> 74 bytes

``` u=(n,c=n+1)=>c?u(n,--c).concat(`${c}`.split``.reverse().join``==c?c:[]):[] ```

u is function.

<s>There's got to be a better way to golf the loop. Php is annoying but at least it has builtins...</s>

<s>Rewrote the whole thing, recursive now. Is there something else for array.concat that pushes nothing?</s>

Why did I have a random argument that did nothing?

Comment: When answering with a function, you don't have to assign it to a variable.

Comment: @xigoi I think I do, because I need to push to result if necessary. Unless I try a recursive function... Back in 15 mins.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ĖæḲ=
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCU5NiVDMyVBNiVFMSVCOCVCMiUzRCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEwMDAmZmxhZ3M9Tg==)

##### Explanation

```python
ĖæḲ=  # Implicit input
Ė     # Push [0..input]
 æ    # Filter by:
  Ḳ   #  Bifurcate it
   =  #  Are they equal?
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```perl6
.flip-$_||.say for 0..slurp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/18vLSezQFclvqZGrzixUiEtv0jBQE@vOKe0qOD/f0tLSwA)

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL, 72

```
DECLARE @@ INT=X,@ INT=0#:IF @=REVERSE(@)PRINT @ SET @+=1IF @<=@@ GOTO #
```

Replace "X" with the input number.  This code runs in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 6 bytes

```
S#`D_q
```

Explanation:

```
S      - range(1, input()+1)
 #     - filter where True
  `D_q -  str(num) == str(num)[::-1]
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=S%23%60D_q&input=99)

Answer (score 0):

## Visual Basic for Applications, 66 bytes

Callable from the immediate window.

```
Sub u(b)
For i=0To b
If StrReverse(i)=i Then Debug.?i
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [characters](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
çi/i∩≈f
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=87692f69eff766&i=515&a=1)

### Explanation

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
^rfcEcr=
^r          [0..n]
  f         Print each element that matches the predicate on individual line
   cE       Array of decimal digits
     cr=    Equals its reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 98 bytes

```js
n=>new Array(n+1).fill().map((a,b)=>b).filter(a=>[...''+a].reverse().join``==''+a&&(a<=n)).join` `
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 67 bytes

```powershell
0..$args[0]|%{$x=[string]$_;if($x-eq(-join$x[-1..-$x.length])){$x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCoAgEADAz2ygBxc7dIpeIhIdTA3RUiGhfPvW3OdMt8nFmRCIJCJs2RYl9Ts80BZVavbRalhnvzNowlxMHMlHaEqMiAIaBhNtdZrzP/RORJOUHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
f n=filter(\x->show x==(reverse.show)x)[0..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzYtM6cktUgjpkLXrjgjv1yhwtZWoyi1LLWoOFUPJKBZoRltoKeXF/s/NzEzT8FWoaC0JLikyCdPQUUBrEFFIU3B0MDgPwA)

Input is an `Int`, output is a `[Int]`